# Is radius of convergence correct for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\bigg(3+(-1)^n\bigg)^n}{n}x^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, power-series

I believe I have the correct answer but I'm not 100% confident in one of the simplification steps that I took:

The series in question is

> $$F(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\bigg(3+(-1)^n\bigg)^n}{n}x^n$$

Here I applied the ratio test. After simplifying I got

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\bigg(3+(-1)^{n+1}\bigg)^{n+1}x^{n+1}}{n+1} \times
\frac{n}{\bigg(3+(-1)^n\bigg)^nx^n}$$

Now I did some cancellations, and here I'm not sure if I did it correctly.  I got:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(3+(-1))xn}{n+1}$$

Then I factored out the absolute value of $x$ and got the limit to be $2$ therefore concluded that $2x<1$ then $x<\frac 12$ therefore the radius of convergence is $\frac 12$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the radius of convergence is $1/4$. Let $r$ be the radius of convergence of the series. Then

$$\frac{1}{r} = \limsup_{n\to \infty} \left|\frac{(3 + (-1)^n)^n}{n}\right|^{1/n} = \limsup_{n\to \infty} \frac{3 + (-1)^n}{n^{1/n}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n^{1/n}}\cdot \limsup_{n\to \infty} [3 + (-1)^n] = 4$$

and thus $r = 1/4$.

Comment: what test are you applying is it the root test? and what is 'sup'?

Comment: The radius of convergence $r$ of a power series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n x^n$ is defined by $\frac{1}{r} = \limsup_{n\to \infty} |a_n|^{1/n}$. The superior limit of a sequence $b_n$, $\limsup_{n\to \infty} b_n$, is defined as $\lim_{n\to \infty} (\sup_{k\ge n} b_n)$ -- the 'sup' means the least upper bound.

Comment: sorry for bothering you but is my approach completely wrong or did I mess up somewhere

Comment: Your approach is wrong. Even if you intended to use the ratio test, you're supposed to take the absolute value in your limit expressions. Even then, the limit does does not exist. So you cannot apply the version of the ratio test you've seen in introductory calculus courses.

Comment: Okay thank you for answering